# Maintaining atomicity of Firestore writes too large for a batch operation (>500)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Firestore allows a maximum of 500 operations in a batch.

If you want to upload a complex document with subcollections that each have hundreds of documents, how are you supposed to ensure an atomic upload?

**This question has been asked multiple times on SO, but all of them are some variation of `"make multiple batches and retry if one fails"` which IS NOT atomic.**

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.  If it were, it would have already been described in the other questions that you're referring to.  This is a documented limitation of Firestore, and you'll have to work with it as-is.

The hard limit documentation can be found [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#writes_and_transactions):

> Maximum number of writes that can be passed to a Commit operation or
>   performed in a transaction: 500

Comment: I know that, I'm trying to find out how people deal with it, if at all. Storing simple objects in an array as a single document? Some kind of idemopotency implementation? That sort of thing.

Comment: It doesn't really come up that often.  If you need large atomic transactions, Firestore might not be right for your application.  No database can be good at everything - there are always tradeoffs.